# Как выполнить Сжатие и восстановление Access базы через Interop?

Tags: c#, .net, com, ms-access, office-interop

Как выполнить Сжатие и восстановление **Access** базы через `Interop`?

Есть класс, который содержит метод:

```
public bool TryCompactAndRepair()
{
    string pathToDb = app.CurrentDb().Name;
    string pathToCompact = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToDb), 
        Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pathToDb)) + 
        "_compact" + Path.GetExtension(pathToDb);

    db.Close();
    app.CloseCurrentDatabase();
    //   Marshal.ReleaseComObject(db);
    GC.Collect();
    if (app.CompactRepair(pathToDb, pathToCompact, true))
    {
        File.Delete(pathToDb);
        File.Move(pathToCompact, pathToDb);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        File.Delete(pathToCompact);
    }
    return false;
}
```

переменная `app` имеет тип `Application`.

Почему-то такой метод возвращает различные ошибки:

1. В текущем виде, что-то вроде *"Object no longer set"*
2. Если раскоментить `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(db);` ,то получаю ошибку, что доступ к объекту не доступен.
3. Если вообще не делать Close, то вылетает ошибка, что нельзя сделать сжатие для текущей БД.

Подскажите, в чем косяк?

Comment: А у вас есть пример сжатия на VBS, JS или c++? кинте ссылку - я покажу как на c#

Comment: Возможно через DAO (ActiveX, microsoft) можно выполнить сжатие.

Answer (score 1):

Вызов `app.CurrentDb().Name` создает управляемую обертку COM-объекта `dao.Database`, ссылка на которую нигде не сохраняется, так что ее никак нельзя впоследствии освободить, кроме как финализатором. Из-за этого программа держит базу даже после вызовов `app.CloseCurrentDatabase()` и `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` на втором экземпляре объекта. Вызов `GC.Collect()` не помогает, так как финализатор выполняется не сразу, а только через некоторое время.

Чтобы нормально освободить базу, нужно избавиться от создания второго экземпляра объекта (так как он не нужен):

```
dao.Database db = app.CurrentDb();

string pathToDb = db.Name;
string pathToCompact = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToDb),
    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pathToDb)) +
    "_compact" + Path.GetExtension(pathToDb);

app.CloseCurrentDatabase();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(db); 

app.CompactRepair(pathToDb, pathToCompact, true);
```